# What do these parameters mean in package h5 in R

Tags: r, hdf

I am using the package `h5` in R to write a library. So for the same reason I am trying to build a dataset from scratch with the function `createDataSet` like so,

```
createDataSet(.Object=HDF.handle,datasetname="chrX2",data=matrix(nrow=10,ncol=10,data=NA),compression=0L,chunksize=4L,type="double")
```

which results in an error message:

```
unable to find an inherited method for function ‘createDataSet’ for signature ‘"H5File", "character", "matrix", "character", "missing", "integer", "missing", "integer", "missing"’
```

I have narrowed it down to the `type`, `dimensions`, `maxdimensions` parameters which I was providing to the function.

Regarding `type`, the manual says `character; Character specifying data type, can be either one of:`, therefore a character vector of length 1 specifying "double" should be valid.

I also considered the possibility that the package may infer the data type of the matrix from the provided matrix, because specifying `matrix(nrow=10,ncol=10,data=NA)` generates a matrix containing NAs of data type logical. This would in turn conflict with the `type` parameter.

**Can someone tell me what is it that I am doing wrong in this case.**

Additionally, regarding the `dimensions` and `maxdimensions` parameters. It is not very clear to me what these parameters control.

From the manual, 
dimensions is defined as 
`integer; Dimensions of dataset to be created.`

and `maxdimensions` is defined as `integer; Maximum dimensions used for dataset, NA sets maxdimensions to ’unlimited’`

I am a bit confused as the shape of a dataset in HDF formats once created cannot be changed without deleting the dataset. In such a case what does `maxdim` control?

**Is this somehow related to the shape of the data which is provided?**

So `dimensions` for a matrix should be `c(nrow(matrix),ncol(matrix))` and so `maxdim` should also be the same.

link to the manual [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/h5/h5.pdf)

**UPDATE**

I got the dataset created. I found out that the conflict lies between the parameters `data` and the three parameters mentioned above. Removing data from the parameter list fixes the issue, but it still does not make it very clear to me what `maxdimensions` really does while creating a dataset.

```
createDataSet(.Object=GroupHandler,
datasetname="chrX",
type="double",
chunksize=4,
compression=9, 
dimensions=c(length(chrX.ranges),length(chrX.ranges)), 
maxdimensions=c(length(chrX.ranges),length(chrX.ranges)))
```